# Magento 2 dimensions attribute code changed

Tags: magento2, import

Currently I am trying to import products from Magento 2.1.15 store to Magento 2.3.1.

I have noticed i cannot import my dimensions like height, length, width.

apparently magento changed the attribute code from `height` etc. to `ts_dimensions_height` and it will not let me import my information even if i change the columns from `height` to `ts_dimensions_height` in my .csv file that I am importing.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the **.csv** file looks like when I want to import dimensions:

```
sku;store_view_code;additional_attributes
PT0602BW;default;"ts_dimensions_height=1234.0000,ts_dimensions_length=12.0000,ts_dimensions_width=123.0000"
```